# last row insert into database while reading the XML file using Jaxb2 java

Tags: java, spring, xml-parsing, jaxb, spring-batch

I am trying to read the XML file, in the array list I have all the records but while saving data into MySQL DB only the last array list data will insert.
Kindly help me how to save all rows in the database.
Below is my step1

```
@Bean
 public Step step1() {
      return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
        .<XML_File_Model, XML_File_Model> chunk(10)
        .reader(reader(null))
        .writer(writer())
        .build();
 }
```

In the XML_File_Model class, I have a list of RootElement

```
    @XmlRootElement(name = "XML_FILE")
    @XmlAccessorType (XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public class XML_File_Model{
        @XmlElement(name = "Transaction")
        private List <Transaction> transaction= new ArrayList<>();
        @XmlElement(name = "Amended_TRN")
        private List <AmendedTransaction> amendedTransaction= new 
        ArrayList<>();
public List <Transaction> getTransaction() {
        return transaction;
    }

    public void setTransaction(List <Transaction> transaction) {
        this.transaction = transaction;
    }

    public List <AmendedTransaction> getAmendedTransaction() {
        return amendedTransaction;
    }

    public void setAmendedTransaction(List <AmendedTransaction> amendedTransaction) {
        this.amendedTransaction = amendedTransaction;
    }
```

AmendedTransaction Model Class

```
 @XmlRootElement(name = "Amended_TRN")
        @XmlAccessorType (XmlAccessType.FIELD)
        public class AmendedTransaction{
            @XmlElement(name = "Item")
        private List <InventoryItem> inventoryItem= new ArrayList<>();
        private String Amended_TRN_Date;
        private String Amended_TRN_Time;

public List <InventoryItem> getInventoryItem() {
        return inventoryItem;
    }

    public void setInventoryItem(List <InventoryItem> inventoryItem) {
        this.inventoryItem = inventoryItem;
    }

@XmlElement(name = "Amended_TRN_Date")
    public String getAmended_TRN_Date() {
        return Amended_TRN_Date;
    }

    public void setAmended_TRN_Date(String amended_TRN_Date) {
        Amended_TRN_Date = amended_TRN_Date;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "Amended_TRN_Time")
    public String getAmended_TRN_Time() {
        return Amended_TRN_Time;
    }

    public void setAmended_TRN_Time(String amended_TRN_Time) {
        Amended_TRN_Time = amended_TRN_Time;
    }
```

Transaction Model Class

```
    @XmlRootElement(name = "Transaction")
            @XmlAccessorType (XmlAccessType.FIELD)
            public class Transaction{
                @XmlElement(name = "Item")
            private List <InventoryItem> inventoryItem= new ArrayList<>();
            private String S_18_Description_Gas_Coupon;
            private String Ticket_Number;
            private String Trans_Time_HHMMSS;
            private String Trans_Date;
    public List <InventoryItem> getInventoryItem() {
        return inventoryItem;
    }

    public void setInventoryItem(List <InventoryItem> inventoryItem) {
        this.inventoryItem = inventoryItem;
    }
@XmlElement(name = "S_18_Description_Gas_Coupon")
    public String getS_18_Description_Gas_Coupon() {
        return S_18_Description_Gas_Coupon;
    }

    public void setS_18_Description_Gas_Coupon(String s_18_Description_Gas_Coupon) {
        S_18_Description_Gas_Coupon = s_18_Description_Gas_Coupon;
    }
    @XmlElement(name = "Ticket_Number")
        public String getTicket_Number() {
            return Ticket_Number;
        }
    
        public void setTicket_Number(String ticket_Number) {
            Ticket_Number = ticket_Number;
        }
    
    @XmlElement(name = "Trans_Time_HHMMSS")
        public String getTrans_Time_HHMMSS() {
            return Trans_Time_HHMMSS;
        }
    
        public void setTrans_Time_HHMMSS(String trans_Time_HHMMSS) {
            Trans_Time_HHMMSS = trans_Time_HHMMSS;
        }
        @XmlElement(name = "Trans_Date")
        public String getTrans_Date() {
            return Trans_Date;
        }
        public void setTrans_Date(String trans_Date) {
        Trans_Date = trans_Date;
        }
```

Writer Code

```
@Bean
     public JdbcBatchItemWriter<XML_File_Model> writer() {
          JdbcBatchItemWriter<XML_File_Model> writer = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<XML_File_Model>();
          writer.setDataSource(dataSource);
          writer.setSql("insert into xml_salesinsert into xml_sales(S_18_Description_Gas_Coupon,Ticket_Number,Trans_Time_HHMMSS,Trans_Date,Item_Number,English_Description,French_Description,Department,Amended_TRN_Date,Amended_TRN_Time) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"); 
          writer.setItemPreparedStatementSetter(new CompanyDetailsItemPreparedStmSetter());
          
            return writer;
        }
```

Reader Code

```
@StepScope
    public StaxEventItemReader<XML_File_Model> reader(@Value("#{jobParameters[file_path]}") String filePath) {
          StaxEventItemReader<XML_File_Model> reader = new StaxEventItemReader<>();
          final FileSystemResource fileResource = new FileSystemResource(filePath);
          reader.setResource(fileResource);
          reader.setFragmentRootElementNames(new String[] {"XML_FILE"});
          Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
          marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(XML_File_Model.class);
          reader.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
return reader;
     }
```

CompanyDetailsItemPreparedStmSetter Class

```
@Override
      public void setValues(XML_File_Model xmlFile, PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
       if(xmlFile.getTransaction().size()>0) {
      for(int i=0; i<xmlFile.getTransaction().size(); i++) {
          ps.setString(1, xmlFile.getTransaction().get(i).getS_18_Description_Gas_Coupon());
          ps.setString(2, xmlFile.getTransaction().get(i).getTicket_Number());
          ps.setString(3, xmlFile.getTransaction().get(i).getTrans_Time_HHMMSS());
          ps.setString(4, xmlFile.getTransaction().get(i).getTrans_Date());

          
          
   if(xmlFile.getTransaction().get(i).getInventoryItem().size()>0 && xmlFile.getTransaction().get(i).getInventoryItem().get(0).getItem_Number()!="" &&
           xmlFile.getTransaction().get(i).getInventoryItem().get(0).getItem_Number()!=null) {
   ps.setString(5, xmlFile.getTransaction().get(i).getInventoryItem().get(0).getItem_Number());
   ps.setString(6, xmlFile.getTransaction().get(i).getInventoryItem().get(0).getEnglish_Description());
   ps.setString(7, xmlFile.getTransaction().get(i).getInventoryItem().get(0).getFrench_Description());
   ps.setString(8, xmlFile.getTransaction().get(i).getInventoryItem().get(0).getDepartment());
   ps.setString(9, default value will pass);
   ps.setString(10, default value will pass);   
  }// if item end here
   
      }// for loop end here
      
      }//if transaction end here
      else if(xmlFile.getAmendedTransaction().size()>0) {
          for(int j=0; j<xmlFile.getAmendedTransaction().size(); j++) {
              ps.setString(1, xmlFile.getAmendedTransaction().get(j).getS_18_Description_Gas_Coupon());
              ps.setString(2, default value will pass);
              ps.setString(3, default value will pass);
              ps.setString(4, default value will pass);
             
              
      if(xmlFile.getAmendedTransaction().get(j).getInventoryItem().size()>0 && xmlFile.getAmendedTransaction().get(j).getInventoryItem().get(0).getItem_Number()!="" &&
               xmlFile.getAmendedTransaction().get(j).getInventoryItem().get(0).getItem_Number()!=null) {
       ps.setString(5, xmlFile.getAmendedTransaction().get(j).getInventoryItem().get(0).getItem_Number());
       ps.setString(6, xmlFile.getAmendedTransaction().get(j).getInventoryItem().get(0).getEnglish_Description());
       ps.setString(7, xmlFile.getAmendedTransaction().get(j).getInventoryItem().get(0).getFrench_Description());
       ps.setString(8, xmlFile.getAmendedTransaction().get(j).getInventoryItem().get(0).getDepartment());
          
      }
      ps.setString(9, xmlFile.getAmendedTransaction().get(j).getAmended_TRN_Date());
      ps.setString(10, xmlFile.getAmendedTransaction().get(j).getAmended_TRN_Time());
       
          }
      }
}
```

XML FILE

```
    <XML_FILE>
    <Transaction>
    <S_18_Description_Gas_Coupon></S_18_Description_Gas_Coupon>
    <Ticket_Number></Ticket_Number>
    <Item>
    <Item_Number></Item_Number>
    <English_Description></English_Description>
    <French_Description></French_Description>
    <Department></Department>
    </Item>
    <Trans_Time_HHMMSS></Trans_Time_HHMMSS>
    <Trans_Date></Trans_Date>
    </Transaction>
    <Transaction>
    <S_18_Description_Gas_Coupon></S_18_Description_Gas_Coupon>
    <Ticket_Number></Ticket_Number>
    <Item>
    <Item_Number></Item_Number>
    <English_Description></English_Description>
    <French_Description></French_Description>
    <Department></Department>
    </Item>
    <Item>
    <Item_Number></Item_Number>
    <English_Description></English_Description>
    <French_Description></French_Description>
    <Department></Department>
    </Item>
    <Trans_Time_HHMMSS></Trans_Time_HHMMSS>
    <Trans_Date></Trans_Date>
    </Transaction>
    <Transaction>
    <S_18_Description_Gas_Coupon></S_18_Description_Gas_Coupon>
    <Ticket_Number></Ticket_Number>
    <Item>
    <Item_Number></Item_Number>
    <English_Description></English_Description>
    <French_Description></French_Description>
    <Department></Department>
    </Item>
    <Item>
    <Item_Number></Item_Number>
    <English_Description></English_Description>
    <French_Description></French_Description>
    <Department></Department>
    </Item>
    <Trans_Time_HHMMSS></Trans_Time_HHMMSS>
    <Trans_Date></Trans_Date>
    </Transaction>
<Amended_TRN>
<Amended_TRN_Sequence> 1</Amended_TRN_Sequence>
<Amended_TRN_Date>20211103</Amended_TRN_Date>
<Amended_TRN_Time>133046</Amended_TRN_Time>
<Amended_TRN_REASON>CompletionOfPrepay</Amended_TRN_REASON>
<Trans_Time_HHMMSS>132924</Trans_Time_HHMMSS>
<S_18_Description_Gas_Coupon></S_18_Description_Gas_Coupon>
    <Item>
    <Item_Number></Item_Number>
    <English_Description></English_Description>
    <French_Description></French_Description>
    <Department></Department>
    </Item>
<Item>
    <Item_Number></Item_Number>
    <English_Description></English_Description>
    <French_Description></French_Description>
    <Department></Department>
    </Item>
<Transaction_End_Time>211103132924</Transaction_End_Time>
<Transaction_Start_Date>20211103</Transaction_Start_Date>
<Transaction_Start_Time>132910</Transaction_Start_Time>
</Amended_TRN>
<Amended_TRN>
<Amended_TRN_Sequence> 1</Amended_TRN_Sequence>
<Amended_TRN_Date>20211103</Amended_TRN_Date>
<Amended_TRN_Time>133123</Amended_TRN_Time>
<Amended_TRN_REASON>CompletionOfPrepay</Amended_TRN_REASON>
<Trans_Time_HHMMSS>132854</Trans_Time_HHMMSS>
    <S_18_Description_Gas_Coupon></S_18_Description_Gas_Coupon>    
  <Item>
    <Item_Number></Item_Number>
    <English_Description></English_Description>
    <French_Description></French_Description>
    <Department></Department>
    </Item>
<Item>
    <Item_Number></Item_Number>
    <English_Description></English_Description>
    <French_Description></French_Description>
    <Department></Department>
    </Item>
<Transaction_End_Time>211103132854</Transaction_End_Time>
<Transaction_Start_Date>20211103</Transaction_Start_Date>
<Transaction_Start_Time>132838</Transaction_Start_Time>
</Amended_TRN>
    </XML_FILE>
```

Comment: Without knowing and seeing what your readers and writers do this will be impossible to answer.

Comment: I updated the code by adding reader and writer. Thanks

Comment: And what does the XML look like and what does your `CompanyDetailsItemPreparedStmSetter` look like.

Comment: I updated the code.

Comment: ANy change that `Item_Number` is used as a primary key and that those are the same? I also don't get your xml reading as you are reading the whole element in one go? Shouldn't the `Transaction` element be the root one or maybe even `Item`? Currently I would say your code doesn't make sense unless you implemented a `getItem_Number` method on the xml file object.

Comment: Item_Number  is not a primary key in Transaction tag ticket_number is the primary key. we can't make the item as root because we need an ticket_number from transaction tag. I forget to add the ticket number in the above code.

Comment: THen at least the `Transaction` should be the tag to read and not the file. And you should write an insert per item and I suspect you are only doing 1 per transaction (looking at your code).

Comment: Actually I have another tag after transaction tag that name is <Amd_transaction ></Amd_transaction>. I actually want to read both tags. Half of my data is under the Transaction tag and half data is under<Amd_transaction>. But <Amd_transaction> XML body is same as the Transaction tag.

Comment: Please add actual code and not some dumbed down version of what you do. But as stated it looks like the problem is in your writing as your code doesn't make sense with the collection you have. You have a nested multi list structure but only read one element (judging by the code you posted so far).

Comment: I will add the actual code.

Comment: I updated the code, Please check now. Thanks

Comment: Your prepared statement setter is wrong. This will only insert the last item of the last transaction for the chunk. What you should do is write a processor that converts your result into a single row per item you need to store. Then rewrite your batch setter.

Comment: yes, this is the problem only the last row is inserted however I want to insert all rows but I am confused about the code can you please help me out with writing this code.

Comment: As I stated you need to write a processors that flattens your read model into a write model (i.e. create a DTO for the row and fill that based on the information you need). That DTO should be written not the XML.

Comment: Could you please help me by sharing some examples, I am still stuck on this issue