# How to read XML file multi Fragments Spring batch Java

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, jaxb, spring-batch

I want to read multiple fragments but while saving them into the database and only the last item is inserted into DB. I attached the Reader, writer, getter setter, and XML file. In the Transaction class, I have the list of items that I want to read.

Reader Code
Below is the code of the reader.

```
@Bean
    @StepScope
    public StaxEventItemReader<Transaction> reader(@Value("#{jobParameters[file_path]}") String filePath) {
          StaxEventItemReader<Transaction> reader = new StaxEventItemReader<>();
          final FileSystemResource fileResource = new FileSystemResource(filePath);
          reader.setResource(fileResource);
          reader.setFragmentRootElementName("Transaction");
          Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
          marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(Transaction.class);
          reader.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
          return reader;
     }
```

Writer Code

```
@Bean
     public JdbcBatchItemWriter<Transaction> writer() {
          JdbcBatchItemWriter<Transaction> writer = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<Transaction>();
          writer.setDataSource(dataSource);
          writer.setSql("insert into xml_sales(S_18_DESCRIPTION_GAS_COUPON,S_18_Description_Manufacturers,S_18_Description_Gift_Certificate,S_18_Description_Other_Coupon,S_11_Global_Payments_KIOSK_Merchant_ID,S_20_Global_Payments_Company,S_20_Global_Payments_Address_0,S_20_Global_Payments_Address_1, S_20_Global_Payments_Address_2, S_8_Global_Payments_Store,S_18_Description_Cash_Off,Item_Number,English_Description,French_Description,Department,Department_Description,Total_Without_Tax,Total_With_Tax,Quantity,GST,UPC,PCATS_PRODUCT_CODE,Price,Mix_And_Match_Group_Number,Price_Group,Deposit_Total,Material_Code,Unmodified_Price,Prompt_For_Price,Ticket_Number,Trans_Time_HHMMSS,Trans_Date,Amended_TRN_Date,Amended_TRN_Time) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");           
          writer.setItemPreparedStatementSetter(new CompanyDetailsItemPreparedStmSetter());
          
            return writer;
        }
```

Getter Setter Class

```
public class CompanyDetailsItemPreparedStmSetter  implements ItemPreparedStatementSetter<Transaction>{

      @Override
      public void setValues(Transaction transaction, PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
       ps.setString(1, transaction.getS_18_Description_Gas_Coupon());
       ps.setString(2, transaction.getS_18_Description_Manufacturers());
       ps.setString(3, transaction.getS_18_Description_Gift_Certificate());
       ps.setString(4, transaction.getS_18_Description_Other_Coupon());
       ps.setString(5, transaction.getS_11_Global_Payments_KIOSK_Merchant_ID());
       ps.setString(6, transaction.getS_20_Global_Payments_Company());
       ps.setString(7, transaction.getS_20_Global_Payments_Address_0());
       ps.setString(8, transaction.getS_20_Global_Payments_Address_1());
       ps.setString(9, transaction.getS_20_Global_Payments_Address_2());
       ps.setString(10, transaction.getS_8_Global_Payments_Store());
       ps.setString(11, transaction.getS_18_Description_Cash_Off());
       
       
       if(transaction.getInventoryItem().size()>0) {
           
       for(int i=0; i<transaction.getInventoryItem().size(); i++){
               
       if(transaction.getInventoryItem().get(i).getItem_Number()!="" &&
               transaction.getInventoryItem().get(i).getItem_Number()!=null) {
           
       ps.setString(12, transaction.getInventoryItem().get(i).getItem_Number());
       ps.setString(13, transaction.getInventoryItem().get(i).getEnglish_Description());
       ps.setString(14, transaction.getInventoryItem().get(i).getFrench_Description());
       ps.setString(15, transaction.getInventoryItem().get(i).getDepartment());
       ps.setString(16, transaction.getInventoryItem().get(i).getDepartment_Description());
       ps.setString(17, transaction.getInventoryItem().get(i).getTotal_Without_Tax());
       ps.setString(18, transaction.getInventoryItem().get(i).getTotal_With_Tax());
       ps.setString(19, transaction.getInventoryItem().get(i).getQuantity());
       ps.setString(20, transaction.getInventoryItem().get(i).getGST());
       ps.setString(21, transaction.getInventoryItem().get(i).getUPC());
       ps.setString(22, transaction.getInventoryItem().get(i).getPCATS_PRODUCT_CODE());
       ps.setString(23, transaction.getInventoryItem().get(i).getPrice());
       ps.setString(24, transaction.getInventoryItem().get(i).getMix_And_Match_Group_Number());
       ps.setString(25, transaction.getInventoryItem().get(i).getPrice_Group());
       ps.setString(26, transaction.getInventoryItem().get(i).getDeposit_Total());
       ps.setString(27, transaction.getInventoryItem().get(i).getMaterial_Code());
       ps.setString(28, transaction.getInventoryItem().get(i).getUnmodified_Price());
       ps.setString(29, transaction.getInventoryItem().get(i).getPrompt_For_Price());
           
       }
      }//inside for loop if      
       
       }//main if
```

XML File

```
<XML_FILE>
    <Transaction>
    <S_18_Description_Gas_Coupon></S_18_Description_Gas_Coupon>
    <Ticket_Number></Ticket_Number>
    <Item>
    <Item_Number></Item_Number>
    <English_Description></English_Description>
    <French_Description></French_Description>
    <Department></Department>
    </Item>
    <Trans_Time_HHMMSS></Trans_Time_HHMMSS>
    <Trans_Date></Trans_Date>
    </Transaction>
    <Transaction>
    <S_18_Description_Gas_Coupon></S_18_Description_Gas_Coupon>
    <Ticket_Number></Ticket_Number>
    <Item>
    <Item_Number></Item_Number>
    <English_Description></English_Description>
    <French_Description></French_Description>
    <Department></Department>
    </Item>
    <Item>
    <Item_Number></Item_Number>
    <English_Description></English_Description>
    <French_Description></French_Description>
    <Department></Department>
    </Item>
    <Trans_Time_HHMMSS></Trans_Time_HHMMSS>
    <Trans_Date></Trans_Date>
    </Transaction>
    <Transaction>
    <S_18_Description_Gas_Coupon></S_18_Description_Gas_Coupon>
    <Ticket_Number></Ticket_Number>
    <Item>
    <Item_Number></Item_Number>
    <English_Description></English_Description>
    <French_Description></French_Description>
    <Department></Department>
    </Item>
    <Item>
    <Item_Number></Item_Number>
    <English_Description></English_Description>
    <French_Description></French_Description>
    <Department></Department>
    </Item>
    <Trans_Time_HHMMSS></Trans_Time_HHMMSS>
    <Trans_Date></Trans_Date>
    </Transaction>
</XML_FILE>
```

Comment: You asked the exact [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70093109/last-row-insert-into-database-while-reading-the-xml-file-using-jaxb2-java) on 24th of november. The answer/solution is already in the comments. Asking the same question again (and still trying the same solution you already had), wont change the solution.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the exact [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70093109/last-row-insert-into-database-while-reading-the-xml-file-using-jaxb2-java) was asked on 24th of november.

Comment: I have no idea how to solve this issue. I tried a lot. Can you please share some example.

Comment: Could you please help me by sharing some examples, I am stuck on this issue still